# How to represent real numbers in two places in R programming?

Tags: r

I created a vector `j` in `R code`

```
> j<-c(1:12)
> j
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

I need it to be in two digits, like

```
> j
 [1]  01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
 sprintf("%02d", j)
```

Also see `formatC`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `sub`

```
sub('^(.)$', '0\\1', j)
#[1] "01" "02" "03" "04" "05" "06" "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12"
```